# How to vertically align first lines of text in table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this situation where first table cell contains "name" and second cell some text. Text may have embedded images. When image appears on the first line it pushes down entire first line. It makes first text line to be no longer aligner with first cell text. I want to make first lines of both table cells aligned.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="align">one</td>
        <td>two <img src="http://www.emofaces.com/en/emoticons/v/vampire-emoticon-before-lunch.gif" /> three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdx0qhcc/31/

In following fiddle goal is to align word "one" to word "two". I know i could vertical-align: top; on image, but it pulls text of second cell up and it looks bad therefore it is not an option. Any kind of solution would work really, be it css/javascript/webkit-only solution.

EDIT:
Note that height and width of image may vary. I also updated fiddle with image alignment being "middle". It does not change situation really.

EDIT2:
Final solution "hack" http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcx2vfg/
Thank you everyone

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand the question - is it okay if the text in both cells are aligned to the bottom (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gdx0qhcc/2/)? Or?

Comment: Not really no.. It is like IM chat window where "one" is name of sender and second cell is message. Name is supposed to be at top of message but aligned with first row. I am thinking if we could somehow get only text in first row then height of images on that row could be checked and first cell on each row could be adjusted manually with javascript. But i have no idea how to get text on the first row either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="align">one</td>
    <td>two <img src="http://www.emofaces.com/en/emoticons/v/vampire-emoticon-before-lunch.gif" /> three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table, tr, td {
    border: solid 1px red;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.align {
     vertical-align: top; 
}
```

JavaScript:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
> $('.align').css('padding-top',(parseInt($('img').css('height'))-16)+"px");
> ```
>
> //16 is the line-height });

Comment: Hey man its terribly close, thanks! Only problem is that when image is on second line then alignment becomes wrong. But im pretty sure there is js workaround. Fiddling with it atm.

Comment: Hey i figured out the rest. Than you very much and here is final fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcx2vfg/

Answer (score 1):

Another idea... I think that what you want requires JavaScript, yeah...

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 10px; width: 50px;
}
span img {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -25px; /* Try with -5px. */
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gdx0qhcc/51/)

Answer (score 1):

You can put image into second row: modify HTML and CSS as shown below:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="align">one</td>
        <td>two three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-top:none;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.emofaces.com/en/emoticons/v/vampire-emoticon-before-lunch.gif" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, tr, td {
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.align {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Image is supposed to be in the middle of text. Now its in completely wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a span element:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="align"><span class="align">one</span></td>
        <td><span class="align">two </span><img valing src="http://www.emofaces.com/en/emoticons/v/vampire-emoticon-before-lunch.gif" /><span class="align"> three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: With vertical-align: top; it pushes text to the top, same as using vertical-align: top; on image. But i want to push text of first cell down a bit instead of pushing second cell's text up.

Comment: Like this: `<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: bottom">one</td>
        <td>two <img src="http://www.emofaces.com/en/emoticons/v/vampire-emoticon-before-lunch.gif" /> three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three</td>
    </tr>
</table>`

Comment: and when there are multiple lines in text cell then first cell will be aligned to bottom line, not to top one. This is not as straightforward as it looks.

Comment: I think you should state your problem better, because after every answer there is a "but in this new scenario...".

Answer (score 0):

In your specific problem this will work

```
.align {
    vertical-align: center;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/gdx0qhcc/6/)

Comment: There's no such thing as `vertical-align: center;` - so that rule does  nothing... remove the rule and see that the result is the same

Comment: But image can be of different size and then it will be misaligned again.